Cannot click and draw/drag polygon in @angular-google-maps (not @agm/core)
I have this in my angular 18 project. I use "@angular/google-maps": "^18.2.3" for this. In this map component when I do right click I pull down a custom context menu. There I have an option called Draw polygon below is the method. The problem is I can't drag the point to draw a polygon. When I drag the point in map the entire map is dragged instead of polygon.


public drawNewPolygon(): void {
    const newPolygon: MapPolygonInterface = {
      points: [
        this.rightClickLastPosition, 
        { lat: this.rightClickLastPosition.lat + 0.001, lng: this.rightClickLastPosition.lng + 0.001 }
      ],
      fillColor: this.mapPolygonFillColor,
      strokeColor: this.mapPolygonStrokeColor,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      isEditable: true,
      isDraggable: true
    };
    this.mapPolygons.push(newPolygon);
    this.emitPolygons.emit(this.mapPolygons);
    console.log("New polygon drawn", this.mapPolygons);
  }





<google-map
  height="100vh"
  width="100%"
  [center]="center"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  [fullscreenControl]="false"
  [streetViewControl]="false"
  [mapTypeControl]="false"
  (mapClick)="handleMapClick($event)"
  (mapRightclick)="mapRightClicked($event)"
  (contextmenu)="onContextMenuRightClick($event)"
>
  <map-marker
    *ngFor="let marker of mapMarkers"
    [position]="marker"
    [title]="'Marker Title'"
    (markerClick)="onMarkerClick($event)"
    [options]="markerOptions">
  </map-marker>

  <map-polygon
  *ngFor="let polygon of mapPolygons; let index = index"
  [paths]="polygon.points"
  [polyDraggable]="true"
  [editable]="true"
  [draggable]="true"
  (polyPathsChange)="polyPathsChange($event, index)"
  (polyDblClick)="polyClickEdit($event, polygon, index)"
  (polyRightClick)="polyRightClick($event, polygon, index)"
  (polyMouseOver)="polyHover($event, polygon)"
  (polyMouseOut)="polyMouseOut($event, polygon)"
  (polyDragEnd)="polyDragEnd($event)"
  [zIndex]="999999"
  [options]="{
    strokeColor: polygon.strokeColor,
    strokeWeight: 10,
    fillColor: polygon.fillColor,
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  }"></map-polygon>


  <map-polyline
    *ngFor="let polyline of mapPolylines"
    [path]="polyline.points"
    [options]="{
        strokeColor: polyline.color,
      }"
    (polyPathChange)="polyPathChange($event)"
  ></map-polyline>
</google-map>



Here's a minimal reproduction of the issue stackblitz

Could you share a stackblitz where the issue happen, with the minimal reproducible code, will be good for debugging.

Sure @NarenMurali please wait

@NarenMurali I have updated link for stackblitz. PS: I can't expose my token so use any of your token for test
